# how do i write a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to write a list comprehension that will have print an element out of an array every other element.
How do I do so?

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
output: 2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: List comprehensions don't go well together with printing. One of them is a functional concept, the other is an imperative one. What exactly is it that you want to do? Probably a `for` loop will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: "print an element out of an array every other element" .. I don't understand this very well, do you mean every other element? Even or odd index?

Comment: Can I ask why you need it to be in a list comprehension and not in a `for` loop?

Comment: Do you want every other (i.e., every second) element, as your question seems to ask, or all elements except the first, as your example shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

newarray = [array[i] for i in range(0, len(array), 2)]

print(newarray)
```

The result is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`.

Answer (score 1):

"an element out of an array *every other element*" .. meaning print out every other element?

If you really want to use list comprehension, here are two, one to collect the *even index entries*, the *other the odd* in their respective lists which are then printed out.

```
evens = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(array) if not (i % 2)]
odds  = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(array) if i % 2]

print evens # entries at even index value
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

print odds  # entries at odd index values
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: thank you, but they dont use list comprehension, i need something like. [for i in stuff if 1%2] without the errors

Comment: list comprehension is not suitable for printing unfortunately.

Comment: can't it be used in conjunction?

Comment: @user1436501 see my updated answer using list comprehension to create the list.

Comment: I think you mean `if i % 2` rather than `if elem % 2`. As written, you're taking the modulus of the element and ignoring the index, which makes `enumerate` pretty pointless.

Comment: @ben .. right you are, that was the whole idea behind using enumerate. Thanks for catching that. I'll update it

Comment: @user1436501 How did you get banned from asking questions? I didn't think that was possible. I think people were frustrated by the wording of the question and lack of clarification. SO is not very forgiving sometimes (I've been there). Did any of the answers solve your problem? Since you didn't accept any of the answers I assumed you didn't get what you were looking for or just left.

Comment: @user1436501 For your particular task list comprehension just didn't seem to be the best/first choice, so I used for loops (and there are other ways too), but since you really needed list comprehension I rewrote my answer to use list comprehension.

Comment: @user1436501 just as a final comment, perhaps this will help in navigating SO http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear as to what the final use of the code is, and therefore what the best way to accomplish it is. But if you are wanting to select every second element out of a list, you can just use slice notation:

```
>>> array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> odd = array[::2]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> even = array[1::2]
>>> even
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

This can be generalised to selecting every *nth* element by changing the step parameter, e.g., to select every third element:

```
>>> third = array[::3]
>>> third
[1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: OP really wants list comprehension, see the first comment under my solution.

Comment: IMHO slicing is a better option than a list comprehension to solve the problem as stated in the question, so I think my answer is valid. If they insist on a list comprehension, I assume the example isn't what they are really trying to achieve, or there is some other reason (e.g., homework question) why it has to be a comprehension.

Comment: No argument from me (slicing is the best approach IMO too).. only that my first solution didn't include list comprehension either, but then I got that comment, so I changed it to list comprehension.

Comment: To be honest, the example in the question doesn't match the text so I'm not sure the OP really knows what they want anyway. But on the off chance that somebody searching for how to select every second (or third, or fourth etc) element out of a list stumbles across this question, I think an answer with the slicing option is worth having.

Comment: And looking at the other questions asked by the user I can't help but feel this is a homework question (or "a test for a job [they are] trying to free internship for" as claimed elsewhere).